# docker, where is the aufs root for the docker container

Tags: filesystems, export, docker

How can I get the root folder info for the `aufs` system underlying the docker container?

Say I run `docker run mytag echo 'Done'`, after that, I believe docker will have an abandoned container built on top of `aufs` system. And I want to make use of that `aufs` file system (say with chroot) without doing a `docker save` or `docker export`.

How can I get that? I need to access that stack of aufs file system, so as to create a squashfs file system out of that whole docker system, instead of the tar from `docker export`, because I always do mksquashfs on image file and have never done mksquashfs a system from within that system.

This is `lxc-docker` version 1.2.0 under Ubuntu.

**UPDATE:**

Having tried with Charles' suggestion, I found making a squashfs system from within that system is not feasible:

```
root@1676061f0072:/#  mount --bind / /mnt/root || { echo error bind mount; exit; } # bind-mount container root only
mount: block device / is write-protected, mounting read-only
mount: cannot mount block device / read-only
error bind mount
exit
```

So, I'm taking Usman's answer as the answer.

Thanks

Comment: This is an implementation detail -- which is to say that it isn't promised to be stable, and anything you write that depends on it is absolutely not guaranteed to continue to work with future releases. Also, after your docker run is complete, the root gets cleaned up -- so the layers still exist individually, but there's no instantiated composite remaining.

Comment: I understand that, and I do have found that all previous blogs/writing are no longer working any more. However, I do need to access that stack of aufs file system, I need to create a `squashfs` file system out of it instead of the `tar`. So when docker run is complete, the root gets cleaned up, does that means if I do a `docker export` on a stopped container, the output would be wrong? Anyway, what if I run `bash -i` to keep the session open, where can I find the aufs file system for docker 1.2.0?

Comment: `export`, similarly, sets up the stack while it's running (and removes it immediately after). The `bash -i` approach should work if current versions still do the mount in the host filesystem namespace rather than the container namespace, but I don't know if that's the case -- if it's not, then what you're asking for isn't possible/available.

Comment: Consider executing mksquashfs _inside_ the container and streaming its contents to the outside over stdout. (This gets a lot easier, y'know, when you tell us what you're actually trying to accomplish rather than asking a question about your preferred mechanism to get there without letting us know what you're actually trying to accomplish).

Comment: Strike that -- mksquashfs can't stream over stdout. Should be able to do a bind mount into the container for the destination directory, though. This also has the pleasant advantage of not being tied to the AUFS backend for Docker at all, and being able to work with the LVM backend, the btrfs backend, etc etc.

Comment: ...anyhow, why not ask your real question separately?

Comment: I always do `mksquashfs` on image file and have never done `mksquashfs` a system from within that system. Anyway, let me revive my question, and you give above as an alternative (and better) solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with the comment however the images can be found at `/var/lib/docker/aufs/diff/<id>` where  is the id of the container which you can find using

```
docker inspect <container-name> | grep Id
```

Comment: thanks, but the id of the container doesn't mean much, because it the that whole stack of layers that counts.

Answer (score 1):

Consider running `mksquashfs` within the container itself, with the destination directory mounted (and the root filesystem on a bind mount, so your squashfs image doesn't try to recurse into `/proc`, `/sys`, etc).

Something akin to the below, untested code:

```
docker run --privileged=true -v /path/to/destination:/mnt/dest bash <<'EOF'
  mkdir -p /mnt/root || exit
  mount --bind / /mnt/root || exit             # bind-mount container root only
  mksquashfs /mnt/root /mnt/dest/squashfs.img  # build an image of that root fs
EOF
```

Some tuning might be called for -- I'm not certain whether `/mnt/dest` needs to exist in the container before this can be run, for instance, and the `--privileged` flag may be unnecessary.

This has the advantage of not caring about which Docker backend is in use -- it'll work with LVM and btrfs storage backends just as well as AUFS -- and depending only on supported semantics (so it'll keep working with future releases).